# How to run jshell when I don't have a file to execute?

Tags: java, jshell

I would like to run jshell like this

```
$ jshell --execute 'System.out.println("Hello World")'
Hello World
$
```

So it executes the java single code line and terminates. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a pipe:

```
echo 'System.out.println("Hello World")' | jshell -
```

From `jshell --help`:

> A load-file may also be "-" to indicate standard input, without interactive I/O.